# Smoke Simulation Dissolve does not work

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have another problem with smoke! I thought during rendering that the simulation just stops working but after a few tests, with an easier set up in another scene, it looks like dissolve of the smoke domain is not working right. In one frame all the smoke is there, in the next it is completely away.

This "Away" Frame moves when I change the dissolve parameter. 
Please help me, I'm completely lost. 
Thank you 
Laura
Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rRE-W2XO8i1YlcYtsUnCfLGOQTDS4ws6/view?usp=sharing[image: frame 66 there, 67 not]

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was the adaptive domain. It stops simulating with a small amount of smoke. Without it, it works

Answer (score 0):

under "Cache" you can change the end Frame - it will stop the animation at that frame, that was my solution for your poblem